# Suitescript - Hide Field based on Drop Down Value

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need to hide a field in a record if a certain option is selected in a drop down field. Using the below code no matter what choice I make in the drop down the field is hiding. Any help appreciated:

```
define([], function () {
  /*Field Change event*/
               function fieldChanged(context) {
                    var records = context.currentRecord;
                    if (context.fieldId == 'custbody_pick_ship') {
                        var customElement = context.currentRecord.getField({ fieldId: 'custbody_zone' });
                        var type = records.getValue({
                            fieldId: 'custbody_pick_ship'
                        });

                        if (type = "Pick Up") {
                           customElement.isDisplay = false;
                        } else {
                            customElement.isDisplay = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

return {
fieldChanged: fieldChanged
}
}
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem lies in the line `if (type = "Pick Up")`. A single `=` in JavaScript is an assignment operator, which means you are *setting* the value of the `type` variable to `"Pick Up"`. As `"Pick Up"` is a non-falsy value that expression will always evaluate as true. You need to use either `==` or `===` to test equality (in general [the triple equal is preferable](https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a)).

```
if (type === "Pick Up") {
   customElement.isDisplay = false;
} else {
   customElement.isDisplay = true;
}
```